# Is there any detail about ambulances in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars

As of September 2019, We've seen fire engines:

[image: Circled flying fire engines]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

And also police cars:

[image: Police speeder]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

I am currently struggling to find an image (or a detailed source on [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ambulance)) about ambulances. Any help?

Comment: Bacta tanks may have rendered hospitals and ambulances obsolete, but I'm only speculating.

Comment: @Roger you'd still need ambulances to get injured people to a bacta tank... and we see several hospital-like environments in the movies (ESB, RotJ, RotS, and TLJ).

Comment: @HorusKol or take the bacta tank to the injured (chopped up Anakin/Vader).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The articles on Wookieepedia on [ambulances](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ambulance) and [air ambulances](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Air_ambulance) are both Legends articles. However, in "Star Wars: The Perfect Weapon" we see an ambulance which has flashing lights with a human and droid medic.

> "Help!" Orri shouted, looking frantically around the busy corner. "Help us! I don't know... I don't know what's wrong!"
>
> They were soon surrounded by concerned octogenarian passersby. An ambulance wailed in the distance, barrelling toward them with red lights flashing. Bazine was shaking now, teeth clenched in what looked like a seizure as Orri knelt at her site, acting perfectly helpless and properly scared. A human in a gleaming white uniform leapt out, a white-and-silver GH-8 medical droid hovering by her side.
>
> "What's wrong?" the woman asked as the droid scanned Bazine's body.
>
> Orri shook his head. "I don't know. We were going to get lunch, and she just... collapsed. What is it?"
>
> "Unidentified substance," the droid said in a calm voice. "Immediate chelation and fluid replacement is recommended."
>
> The human nodded and pulled a gurney out of the hovering ambulance. "You can ride in back," she said to Orri, who stood and continued to be useless. Together, the woman and the droid lifted Bazine's stiff body onto the gurney and slid it into the waiting vehicle. Orri climbed in to sit on the bench beside her, one hand on the gurney but definitely not close to touching Bazine, as if he was terrified of her even when she appeared to be dying. The ride was oddly calm and strangely fast. Moments later they slipped down a ramp and into the cool underbelly of the medcenter.

Comment: God, that's terrible writing ...

Comment: I’m no medical expert, but maybe she died of a broken heart

Comment: For an example from the primary films, wasn't the scene @Celestialgranturismo is referencing where Padme dies birthing Luke and Leia in Ep.3 inside some sort of an ambulance ship?  I can't bring myself to watch it again to make sure...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman You may have been mislead- Padme gave birth to Luke and Leia in the medical facilities on [Polis Massa](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Polis_Massa), an asteroid field. If you're looking for _that_ scene you were talking about, it can be found [here on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ohsLZxQYBk8), where you can also see in the opening shot that the station is in a crater on one of the asteroids.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Why is it terrible? It's too short for plot holes or to develop characterization. It just describes a poisoning.

Comment: @Chloe I'm talking about the quality of the writing itself, not the plot. For instance, "*one hand on the gurney but definitely not close to touching Bazine, as if he was terrified of her even when she appeared to be dying. The ride was oddly calm and strangely fast.*" It just reads so unnaturally.

Comment: I was just being a jackass, but now you got me thinking: didn’t Luke get his mechanical hand installed on a Medical Frigate? That’s how I always remember it referred to in materials from when I was a kid (Nebulon-B?... or am I mixed up with Trek?)

Comment: @Celestialgranturismo I think he gets his hand fitted in the medical bay of one of the Rebellions main ships.

Comment: @Randal'Thor OK I guess it is just very subjective then. I don't know what is unnatural about it. I would imagine someone would be afraid to touch a poison victim for fear of being contaminated, similar to the [poisoning of a Russian spy in Britain](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/03/12/world/europe/uk-russia-spy-poisoning.html) which also affected his daughter because she touched him and a medical worker. I would also imagine one's thoughts would be racing and reliving memories and one would be in one's head, unaware of the trip.

Comment: @Chloe It's not *what's* being described, but the *way* it's being described. The style of writing just grates on my eyes/ears. (That said, we're going a bit off-topic in these comments ...)

Comment: would probably help to have read the whole story in context before judging the writing of that particular scene. It's a pretty decent story imo and that's some character stuff happening - it just reads weird because it's a snippet

Comment: @Randal'Thor What feels somewhat forced to me is the overuse of adverbs and adjectives, especially in the style of "adverb adverb and adverb adverb". A small to medium amount of adverts and adjectives is fine, but giving too many nouns adjectives or adverbs breaks the flow.

Answer (score 5):

## Canon

The **U-wings** introduced in *Rogue One* have previously been used for ambulance-like purposes, according to *The Rebel Files*:

> **ROLE:** Multipurpose. To date, the Alliance has deployed the U-wing as:
>
> - Troop transport (at Mantooine)
> - Gunship (in support of the Tocan system extraction)
> - Medevac lifter (during the retreat from Gaulus)
> - As a cargo and VIP escort (between Mon Cala and Telaris and points coreward)

(source: *The Rebel Files*, standalone edition, page 65)

And from the movies themselves, the closest that's been seen so far is **Palpatine's Theta-class shuttle**:

[image: Palpatine's Theta-class shuttle]
(source: [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Theta-class_T-2c_shuttle))

While not primarily intended as an ambulance, it did contain a "medical capsule" in *Revenge of the Sith*, which appears to be a kind of gurney, and transported Darth Vader to a medical facility on Coruscant:

[image: Darth Vader in a medical capsule]

(source: [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Medical_capsule))

## Legends

In addition to the ambulances mentioned in TheLethalCarrot's answer, there are a few other ambulance-like craft:

- [Med Sprinters](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Med_sprinter) seem to be ambulance-like spacecraft for rescuing pilots.
- The Lambda-class shuttle group [Medevac](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Medevac) was also used to transport wounded.
- [Medlifter troop transports](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Medlifter_troop_transport) were airspeeders used in the Clone Wars to transport troops to medical facilities.

Answer (score 4):

In the original Trilogy, Luke has his mechanical hand installed onboard a Nebulon-B medical frigate. While debateable as to whether it was primarily a hospital ship, or a warship with medical facilities, Wedge Antilles refers to it as a medical frigate during the battle of Endor, where it also appears. Also, the Pelta class medical frigate is seen in several episodes of the Clone Wars series, and is specifically used for medevacing Clone Troopers to medica facilities.

Comment: Although a medical frigate is not comparable to an ambulance. We also have "medical frigates" ([hospital ships](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercy-class_hospital_ship), which however typically are not frigates) in our galaxy, and we refer to them distinctly from ambulances. There may be some fuzziness, e.g. the term "air ambulance" for a medevac helicopter, but I don't think a hospital ship would ever be called a "sea ambulance".

Comment: Good points. It gets a little murky. The latter example is clearly shown evacuating Clone Trooper casualties to medical facilities. And while I didn’t mention it, the closest to what I feel the question was going for is the the Republic Gunship (LAAT/I) (Mi-24 Hind looking thing) which functions as a gunship and transport. I would imagine it also ferries casualties out of combat zones as well. I can’t specify any particular circumstance besides the battle of Geonosis, where injured Palme/Jedi are flown out of the battle zone